# SET a variable in mysql only once

Tags: mysql

I am using classic ASP and MySQL (using PHP wouldn't change the point of the question).

I need to set a variable over my homepage:

```
SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc'
```

I can not set it as global variable as other users are using the server and may use the default `block_encryption_mode`.

I know I can use the statement using ASP/PHP on the beginning of each webpage, but that seems like using too much resources; every user will execute the SET statement on every page...

Is there a way to SET variable or execute some other SQL statement at the beggining on each session, like an onstart event like ASP has, maybe? Or how could I achieve my goal without executing the query for each user on every page I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe to call `SET` on every page as it executes in orders of microseconds. There is literally no overhead calling `SET` on already open connection.

Unless you can apply this setting globally, I would not bother. Just set the `block_encryption_mode` (together with `collation` and `timezone`) directly after acquiring the database connection handle.

Comment: But this string executes on every client, also from other websites that do not want this SET to be present...

Comment: As far as I know block_encryption_mode is a session variable, so using SET should not affect other clients. Also, I presume you would need admin rights to set the value further than your own session.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [init_connect](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect) variable.

> A string to be executed by the server for each client that connects. The string consists of one or more SQL statements, separated by semicolon characters.

You can also distinguish the users with code like this:

```
IF (CURRENT_USER() = 'special_crypto_dude@localhost') THEN
    SET SESSION block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
END IF;
```